# Calculate aggregate value of last 12 months in a Measure Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using this measure to calculate a aggregate sum of a value in the last 12 months. The measure is working well if I start using it from the month 12. But, the problem is, if the month is not in the 12 or higher, the value is not right.

Example, if you are in the first month of the sample, I would like to multiply this value by 12 (1st month + 11 months). If it was the second month, I'd like you to average the two months and multiply it by 12. And so on.

could you please help me?

```
SumRevenue  = 
    var vSumNet12 =
    CALCULATE(
        Table[Trevenue],
        DATESINPERIOD(
            CalendarM[Data],
            MAX(CalendarM[Data]),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
    )
    return
    vSumNet12
```

---

Example table:

```
Date    Customer    Net Trevenue    SumRevenue  ROA ROA I Want
09/30/20    A   237767115,6 327444,2478 327444,2478 0,14%   1,65%
10/31/20    A   245689276,3 251934,78   579379,0278 0,24%   1,41%
11/30/20    A   252916933,6 262294,89   841673,9178 0,33%   1,33%
12/31/20    A   241424127   509883,07   1351556,988 0,56%   1,68%
01/31/21    A   244721140,9 259250  1610806,988 0,66%   1,58%
02/28/21    A   250913741,4 246740,33   1857547,318 0,74%   1,48%
03/31/21    A   282215365,7 550897,35   2408444,668 0,85%   1,46%
04/30/21    A   312759343,1 544161,63   2952606,298 0,94%   1,42%
05/31/21    A   325535894   419360,97   3371967,268 1,04%   1,38%
06/30/21    A   371306315   390650,41   3762617,678 1,01%   1,22%
07/31/21    A   379780645,3 527254,43   4289872,108 1,13%   1,23%
08/31/21    A   415390274,9 409196,3    4699068,408 1,13%   1,13%
09/30/21    A   433837730,6 598924,02   4970548,18  1,15%   1,15%
10/31/21    A   482659906,7 254086,32   4972699,72  1,03%   1,03%
11/30/21    A   501568104,7 318924,53   5029329,36  1,00%   1,00%
12/31/21    A   507124350,5 754897,79   5274344,08  1,04%   1,04%
01/31/22    A   510220304,2 179153,11   5194247,19  1,02%   1,02%
```

Comment: Add sample data, what you are getting from you DAX and what you actually wants.

Comment: @mkRabbani added in post